# Not changing permissions as root on git pull

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, root, git, administration

I've been managing a not very big system for a few months now and there are still a couple of issues that I don't like how they're being dealt with right now.

Currently, there is practically just one user that accesses the server, so it might seem that there isn't much trouble, however, this user (and every other that would access the server) has access to a git repository that is continuously changing, and I need it to always be in its latest version. Some time ago, I created a cron job as root to pull all the repositories for all existing users, however that broke the repositories' permissions as files were being written by root, so regular users couldn't do things like "git pull" and so on.

So, my question is if there is some way that lets me update the repositories as root without actually changing the permissions of the git repo directory and subdirectories, or if, alternatively, I would have to create some script that loops over all existing users, logs in as each of those users and then updates the repo so that it won't break their permissions.

The final objective is to automate this task as much as possible, as pulling each repository manually, although it does work, is a solution I don't intend to keep for a long-time period.

Comment: Does the cron job have to run as root? Users can have cron jobs too...

Comment: No, it isn't necessary, precisely running it as root is what it's messing with permissions. So I guess you're saying I can write a cron job that runs under each user's account, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can. Whether that’s useful depends on how many users need to have the same processing applied to them; but user crontabs are a nice way of dealing with permission issues of this kind.

Comment: On some distributions, per-user crontabs can be defined centrally; *e.g.* on Debian and derivatives, in `/etc/cron.d` — each cron definition specifies the user that the job should run as.

Answer (score 0):

Yes one of the thinks that `root` can do. Is change to any arbitrary user.

Therefore

```
as root:
  foreach user: # for user in …
     create a sub-shell: # (stuff todo in sub-shell)
        become that user # sudo
        do the work # git pull
```

You will find it easier to create a sub-shell, to that you can get back to being root (not strictly necessary, but I don't know any other way with the shell).